# how do i get the mouse sensitivity work with the frame rate

Tags: java, mouse

so im working on a fps similar to wolfenstein 3D and im a little stuck on the mouse sensitivity only working properly if the frame rate is at roughly 60.

any ideas on how to fix it?

here is my code.

rays index 90 and 91 are for strafing left and right.
and yes, i do realize now i could just use index 90 and subtract it for strafing right.

i know the issue is because as the framerate decreases(or ellapsedTime increases), the resetMousePos function returns a higher number, and vice-versa, but i dont know how to fix this

```
public static void controls()
{
    angle += resetMousePos() * Engine.ellapsedTime() * turningSpeed;
    System.out.println(resetMousePos() * Engine.ellapsedTime() * turningSpeed);

    if (Window.W())
    {
        pos[0] += (rays.get(45).getDir()[0] * speed) * Engine.ellapsedTime();
        pos[1] += (rays.get(45).getDir()[1] * speed) * Engine.ellapsedTime();
    }

    if (Window.S())
    {
        pos[0] -= (rays.get(45).getDir()[0] * speed) * Engine.ellapsedTime();
        pos[1] -= (rays.get(45).getDir()[1] * speed) * Engine.ellapsedTime();
    }

    if (Window.A())
    {
        pos[0] += (rays.get(90).getDir()[0] * speed) * Engine.ellapsedTime();
        pos[1] += (rays.get(90).getDir()[1] * speed) * Engine.ellapsedTime();
    }

    if (Window.D())
    {
        pos[0] += (rays.get(91).getDir()[0] * speed) * Engine.ellapsedTime();
        pos[1] += (rays.get(91).getDir()[1] * speed) * Engine.ellapsedTime();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rays.size(); i++)
    {
        rays.get(i).setPos(pos);

        if (i < 90)
        {
            rays.get(i).setAngle(Math.toRadians(i + angle));
        }
        if (i == 90)
        {
            rays.get(i).setAngle(Math.toRadians(i + angle + 45));
        }
        if (i == 91)
        {
            rays.get(i).setAngle(Math.toRadians(i + angle + 225));
        }
    }

    if (Window.Space())
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }

}

public static int resetMousePos()
{
    int d = 0;

    Point p = Window.getWindow().getLocation();

    Robot r = null;
    try
    {
        r = new Robot();
    } catch (AWTException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (Window.mouseX() != Window.width() / 2)
    {
        d = (Window.width() / 2) - Window.mouseX();
        r.mouseMove(p.x + 8 + Window.width() / 2, p.y + Window.height() / 2);
    }

    return d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution.
at the line that has the fallowing :

angle += resetMousePos() * Engine.ellapsedTime() * turningSpeed;

i simply replaced Engine.ellapsedTime() with just a double number 0.001
and it works just fine at any frame rate.